# client side validation and display field style in ext.net

Tags: asp.net, css, validation, ext.net

How can I give style to DisplayField with color, font-bold,font-size etc. like in TextField and label, and date format is not as exact display on displayfield. It combine with time even column in database is only date type
Sample:

```
<ext:Toolbar  Dock="Top" ID="toolBar" runat="server">
                        <Items>
                        <ext:DisplayField ID="DisplayField4" runat="server" FieldLabel="Message From" LabelSeparator="" Name="FromName" />
                        <ext:ToolbarSpacer runat="server" Width="25" />
                        <ext:DisplayField ID="DisplayField2" runat="server" Name="DueDate" FieldLabel="Due Date" LabelSeparator="" LabelWidth="60" /> 
                        <ext:ToolbarSpacer ID="ToolbarSpacer1" runat="server" Width="25" /> 

                        <ext:Label runat="server"  Text="Days Remaining" StyleSpec="color:red" />
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Toolbar>
```

Comment: There are two questions. One issue per thread is a good rule. Could you, please, edit the post to leave the only question?

Comment: I have no idea to post only one issue per thread. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Cls property to stylize components.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>

    <style>
        .my-displayfield1 .x-form-display-field {
            color: yellow;
            font-size: large;
        }

        .my-displayfield2 .x-form-display-field {
            color: green;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:DisplayField runat="server" Cls="my-displayfield1" Text="I am DisplayField #1" />

        <ext:DisplayField runat="server" Cls="my-displayfield2" Text="I am DisplayField #2" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using User Control to PopUp A Window with a value from grid. And above code is not acceptable here, I am unable to PopUp a Window that contain in .aspx page instead of .ascx page with a single button click. Is there any way to call a .aspx page with window in another .aspx page to popup a window.

Comment: Also I am already query about display of date format in display field as above which was not solved. Recently I am using FieldStyle Property of DispalyField to give it style.

Comment: Your question was how to stylize a DisplayField. I believe my answer demonstrates it. Could you confirm that? It doesn't look that your follow-up questions are related to stylizing of DisplayFields.

Comment: Actually, I had not post my question clearly. And sure, your answer demonstrates as my above question. Sorry for that again. If you don't mind I am going query problem again here.

Comment: Now my main problem is, I want to popup window which had coded in .aspx page instead of .ascx page. I am able to pop up window as demonstrated here:  "http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Miscellaneous/Details_Window/", but I want that window in .aspx page which must call in another .aspx. And here I have no idea how to call one .aspx page into another .aspx page to pop up window. That window must contain DisplayField with date display, and here how can I give style to FieldLabel of DisplayField and how can I show the date in only date format without time in Name property of DisplayField.

Comment: OK BOSS, I will start again bcoz I need guidance in Ext.Net. Its my first month to work in Ext.Net. If I am unable to perform well, then I will be..............., u can easily guess it.